# Finding Possible Values of GP Common ratio (r)

Tags: sequences-and-series

r is the common ration of a GP (r is not equal to  1)  and the sum of the first 4 terms is 5 times the sum of the first 2 terms. Find the possible values of r.

How do I solve this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $s_n=a(1+r+r^2+...+r^{n-1})$ then it's well-know (or easy to show) that

$$ s_n=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r} $$

What you're given in the question is:

$$ s_4=5s_2 $$

or if you expand this and cancel terms,

$$ (1-r^4)=5(1-r^2) $$

Now solve for $r$.